# Installing imagick PHP extension on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php5, pecl, imagemagick

I'm trying to install the imagick pecl extension on my Ubuntu server and am getting the below error. I've installed the ImageMagick rpm using aptitude already and the pecl extension is version 2.3.0. I've looked around online but can't find anything pointing me in the right direction. I also tried looking for anything that looked like it might be the Wand-config or MagickWand-config program that the error is mentioning but can't find any.

```
steven@server:/var/www$ sudo pecl install imagick
downloading imagick-2.3.0.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-2.3.0.tgz (86,976 bytes)
.....................done: 86,976 bytes
12 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20041225
Zend Module Api No:      20060613
Zend Extension Api No:   220060519
Please provide the prefix of Imagemagick installation [autodetect] :
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-root/imagick-2.3.0
running: /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-imagick
*** ... snip ... ***
checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... configure: error: not found. Please provide a path to MagickWand-config or Wand-config program.
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-imagick' failed
```

I snipped most of the output because it didn't really seem to helpful but I can post if requested.

- PHP is 5.2.4
- ImageMagick is 6.3.7
- Ran `sudo aptitude upgrade` today to upgrade RPMs as well before install ImageMagick

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to install the ImageMagick devel package. In Ubuntu try:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev libmagickcore-dev
```

Comment: I am trying to do the same on alpine linux and it appears the package name is different (imagemagick-dev).

Answer (score 0):

It's in the ubuntu repos (version 2.0.1-1 for hardy), is there a reason you're trying to compile it yourself?

Comment: The version in the ubuntu repo for the version I was on (8.0.4) was 1.x and I needed at least 2.1.x. In the end I ended up upgraded to ubuntu 9 so I didn't have to.